# updating submodules with git-flow

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-flow

When making a release with git, using the git-flow model, I switch my repository to point to the latest commit in master, tag and then build from the tag. Is it good practice to merge changes into master for *all* the repository's submodules, and have them point to master (that is, the latest commit in master), or is it sufficient to leave all submodule commits unchanged?

Answer (score 3):

Your commit on `master` will record the commits of all the submodules that you use.

If somebody checks out the release that you just cut (and tagged), they will be responsible to run `git submodule update` in order to check out the correct commit on each submodule.

Submodule checkouts are always *headless* commits, i.e. addressed by their SHA-1 hash value and not by a symbolic ref (branch name).  Therefore, it does not matter what branch they point to.

All that matters is what commits are recorded on `master` (of the superproject).

So, to answer your question: it's OK to leave the submodule commits unchanged when you make your release.